# ways to check for invalid characters? oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Looking for ways to filter out special signs, letters etc. from studentID in oracle SQL and show those records as invalid.

What is the best way to filter out letters a-Z and other characters? (only leaving numbers)

```
SELECT replace(Translate(studentid,'a-Z<>!-\+=/&', '??'),'?','') as StudentID, 'Invalid Characters in Student ID' 
FROM students
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use regular expressions. For example

```
select studentid
from   student
where  regexp_like(studentid, '\D')
;
```

`\D` means non-digit character; if the `studentid` contains at least one such character, in any position, then it will appear in the output. Note that `null` will not be flagged out, assuming it may appear in the column; perhaps the column is primary key in which case it can't be `null`. But this would apply to other tables as well, where `studentid` may be `null`.

If you have a very large table, or if you must perform this check often, you may want a less simple, but better performing query. Then you would want to use standard string functions, like you were trying to. Something like this will work:

```
select studentid
from   student
where  translate(studentid, 'x0123456789', 'x') is not null
;
```

`translate` will translate `x` to itself, and all digits to `null` (that is, all digits will be removed). The `x` trick is needed because the last argument must not be `null`. If the translation doesn't remove **all** characters from the string, then the `studentid` will appear in the output, as required.

If you need to show exactly which characters are non-digits (although that should be obvious), you can add the result of `translate` to the `select` clause. Note though that if a student id has, for example, trailing spaces, that will not be evident either from looking at the student id or at the result of translate. You may want to add something like `dump(studentid)` to `select`; if you are not familiar with `dump`, you may want to read a bit about it - it is extremely useful in diagnosing such problems, and easy to learn.

Once you find and handle all the exceptions, you may want to add a constraint to the column, to require all student id's to consist entirely of digits. Then you won't have to put up with this kind of errors anymore.

Comment: Another speedup of `translate` for short enough strings (less than 38 characters) may be to use `validate_conversion(studentid as number, '999...9')`, which [takes](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=aef0744a165ce885a6aa1df06da2d048) 20x less time

Comment: @astentx - not really. `validate_conversion` will show strings with leading spaces (like `'   33'`) and strings with a minus sign (like `'-33830'`) as "valid". The OP wants them as "invalid".

Comment: @mathguy would it make sense to make the translate trick into a function?

Comment: @mathguy Good point, thanks. May be fixed with concatenation of zero at the left.

Comment: @Beefstu - only if you need to use this exact trick repeatedly, in many different queries. The concern here is bloat; if you make every little piece of code into a function, you won't even know all the functions you ever created. Worse, someone else reading your code later won't know what the function does, unless you documented it, and they know where to find the documentation. Much more natural to just use `translate` as is - everyone should be able to find the documentation for *that*.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to allow numbers only, column datatype should have been `NUMBER`, not `VARCHAR2`.

**[EDIT]** That's wrong, though - see @mathguy's comment about it, saying that there are situations where values do consist of digits only, but - due to leading zeros - you can't use the `NUMBER` datatype.

---

A simple option is to use `regexp_like` and return rows that contain anything but digits:

```
SQL> with students (studentid) as
  2    (select '12345' from dual union all
  3     select 'ABC12' from dual union all
  4     select '23x#2' from dual
  5    )
  6  select studentid
  7  from students
  8  where not regexp_like(studentid, '^\d+$');

STUDE
-----
ABC12
23x#2

SQL>
```

Comment: The first comment in your answer is wrong. There are legitimate, real-life uses for actual strings (not numbers) that consist entirely of digits. For example postal codes - a postal code like '00324' is perfectly valid, but as number it would become just 324. If postal codes can be of variable length (for example if the table has data from multiple countries), it won't be obvious how to restore the correct code from a number.

Comment: I just love reading both your answers and comments, @mathguy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use below solution taking advantage of translate function.

```sql
  select studentid
  from students
  WHERE translate(studentid, '`0123456789', '`') IS NOT NULL
  ;
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8561efef44fe40b16b840d462749db70)

Comment: You're right @mathguy. I updated the description of my answer. Thanks.